# Docker multi-stage building saves intermediate image

Tags: docker

I've recently started to learn Docker and have been trying to learn how to use multi-stage build.
The documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/
Says

> The end result is the same tiny production image as before, with a
> significant reduction in complexity. You don’t need to create any
> intermediate images and you don’t need to extract any artifacts to
> your local system at all.

There's also an example I don't think is necessary to copy here, however I've also started a small Spring Boot project with Gradle that I want to containerize. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
# using multi-stage to avoid manual ./gradlew build
FROM openjdk:11 as build

COPY gradle gradle
COPY build.gradle build.gradle
COPY gradlew gradlew
COPY gradlew.bat gradlew.bat
COPY settings.gradle settings.gradle
COPY src src

RUN ./gradlew build

# final image
FROM openjdk:11
WORKDIR /service
COPY --from=build /build/libs/*.jar /service/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/service/app.jar"]
```

This is `docker images` command output before the build:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
openjdk             11                  5c6e71a989bc        12 days ago         627MB
```

Build command: `docker build . -t sdemo:1.2.1`
And the `docker images` after it's finished:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
sdemo               1.2.1               24ea50770b2a        13 seconds ago      672MB
<none>              <none>              a1f8e74e1d81        20 seconds ago      960MB
openjdk             11                  5c6e71a989bc        12 days ago         627MB
```

As you can clearly see, I've got 2 images more instead of one, and the unnamed one is of ridiculous size of 960MB. What is causing this problem? Also, if it's relevant, I'm on a virtual box machine running Ubuntu.

The whole project is located under https://github.com/vincent2704/demoSpringBootApp, version 1.2.1 at the moment of posting this question.

Comment: The `<none>:<none>` image matches the first `FROM` block.  It does create an image, but it doesn't have a name, and standard cleanup commands like `docker image prune` can remove it.  (But you may want to keep it to make rebuilds faster.)